# JButton ActionListener (Java 8 JDK 1.8.0_74) is not working

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

I was in the middle of making a program to remove commented lines from any file, I had just finished the main GUI and added two action listeners to my JButtons and then it all broke. I feel like I made a really stupid mistake somewhere but I can't figure out where. Any ideas? (major region is commented out)

```
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicOptionPaneUI.ButtonActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Box;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Font;

public class ReplaceComments{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        createInitialWindow();
    }
    public static void createInitialWindow(){
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int w = (int)screenSize.getWidth();
        int h = (int)screenSize.getHeight();
        System.out.println("Width: " + w +  "\nHeight: " + h + "\nCreating customized window...");
        JLabel explanation1 = new JLabel("Welcome to Comment Replacer 1.0!");
            explanation1.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, w/80));
            explanation1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);            
        JLabel explanation2 = new JLabel("Simply paste in the file you want");
            explanation2.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, w/80));
            explanation2.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        JLabel explanation3 = new JLabel("to remove comments from, and the");
            explanation3.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, w/80));
            explanation3.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        JLabel explanation4 = new JLabel("folder it should output to.");
            explanation4.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, w/80));
            explanation4.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        JLabel Source = new JLabel("Source: ");
            Source.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, w/80));
        JTextField source = new JTextField(w/130);
            source.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, w/80));
        JLabel Output = new JLabel("Output: ");
            Output.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, w/80));
        JTextField output = new JTextField(w/130);
            output.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, w/80));

        /*       \/  This Part  \/       */

        JButton replace = new JButton("Replace");
            replace.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, w/80));
            replace.setSize(new Dimension(w/8,h/8));
            replace.addActionListener(new CustomActionListener(){  /*********************/
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){        /* Added this action */
                    replaceButtonClicked();                        /*  listener and it  */
                }                                                  /*   all broke :3    */
            });                                                    /*********************/
        JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
            cancel.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, w/80));
            cancel.setSize(new Dimension(w/8,h/8));
            cancel.addActionListener(new CustomActionListener(){   /*********************/
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){        /* Added this action */
                    cancelButtonClicked();                         /*  listener and it  */
                }                                                  /*   all broke :3    */
            });                                                    /*********************/

        /*       /\  This Part  /\       */

        ButtonGroup screen1 = new ButtonGroup();
            screen1.add(replace);
            screen1.add(cancel);
        Box info = Box.createVerticalBox();
            info.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(w/100));
            info.add(explanation1);
            info.add(explanation2);
            info.add(explanation3);
            info.add(explanation4);
        Box sourceBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
            sourceBox.add(Source);
            sourceBox.add(source);
        Box outputBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
            outputBox.add(Output);
            outputBox.add(output);
        Box textBoxes = Box.createVerticalBox();
            info.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(w/21));
            textBoxes.add(sourceBox);
            textBoxes.add(outputBox);
        Box buttons = Box.createHorizontalBox();
            buttons.add(replace);
            buttons.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(w/50));
            buttons.add(cancel);
            buttons.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(w/30));
        JPanel upperPanel = new JPanel();
            upperPanel.add(info);
        JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();
            middlePanel.add(textBoxes);
        JPanel lowerPanel = new JPanel();
            lowerPanel.add(buttons);
        BorderLayout border = new BorderLayout();
        JFrame frameWindow = new JFrame("Comment Replacer v1.0");
            frameWindow.add(upperPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            frameWindow.add(middlePanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frameWindow.add(lowerPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            frameWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frameWindow.setSize(w/2,h/2);
            frameWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frameWindow.setVisible(true);   
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
    public void replaceButtonClicked(){
        System.out.println("Replace button clicked!");
        // Do something else
    }
    public void cancelButtonClicked(){
        System.out.println(";-;");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not how SO works. You don't just drop your mess on us; for us to figure out it. First of all: "then it broke" is not a helpful description. What do you mean? Do you have compiler errors; or did your application stop to do what it is supposed to do? You want us to help; so please: you try to make that possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change CustomActionListener by ActionListener

```
  /*       \/  This Part  \/       */

        JButton replace = new JButton("Replace");
            replace.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, w/80));
            replace.setSize(new Dimension(w/8,h/8));
            replace.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  /*********************/
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){        /* Added this action */
                    replaceButtonClicked();                        /*  listener and it  */
                }                                                  /*   all broke :3    */
            });                                                    /*********************/
        JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
            cancel.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, w/80));
            cancel.setSize(new Dimension(w/8,h/8));
            cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){   /*********************/
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){        /* Added this action */
                    cancelButtonClicked();                         /*  listener and it  */
                }                                                  /*   all broke :3    */
            });                                                    /*********************/

        /*       /\  This Part  /\       */
```

and change the methods to static, :

```
        public static void replaceButtonClicked(){
        System.out.println("Replace button clicked!");
        // Do something else
    }
    public static void cancelButtonClicked(){
        System.out.println(";-;");
        System.exit(0);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`static` has it's uses and it's places, this is probably not one of them.  Instead of using `public static void createInitialWindow(){`, make it an instance method, `public void createInitialWindow(){`, then in your `main` method, create an instance of the class and call the method, for example...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            ReplaceComments replaceComments = new ReplaceComments();
            replaceComments.createInitialWindow()
        }
    });
}

public void createInitialWindow(){
    //...
```

This is likely to solve not only this problem, but many others you might encounter which are associated it with it

Answer (score 0):

The code as it is is not working the method must be static

```
public static void replaceButtonClicked(){
    System.out.println("Replace button clicked!");
    // Do something else
}
public static void cancelButtonClicked(){
    System.out.println(";-;");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

in this way the code you posted is working

Comment: How about instead, the OP remove the `static` requirement for the `createInitialWindow` method

Comment: @MadProgrammer it's call in a main method to make this has to istance the class and then call the method, but yes it will work

Comment: So?  Create an instance of the class and call it's method.  The problem is the OP is making to great a reliance on `static` which is not only cause them issues now, but will continue to do so in the future, at least this way, we can stop them from shooting themselves in the foot (and hopeful a few other people's as well)

Comment: yes i like your answer is the best way to do this

Comment: Sorry, I have a real issue with `static` :P